# Intercept a href with target="_blank" in webview

Tags: android, webview

There is any way to intercept a _blank target on

```
<a href="..." target="_blank">
```

tags when using web views in android applications?
That is, if a url is configured with a target blank, my application would open the default device web browser.

Thanks in advance.